# Fiter / IF fucntion in Array (google sheet)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Im in a problem, I always get an error with a formula i am trying to make. So i have a column with € including VAT( J151:J), now i have a Column with the VAT % in there(I151:I). So i make an array formula to calculate al my total VAT and get the result back in one cell. This i get to work with this formula:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA($J$151:$J/100% *$I$151:$I))
```

But in this formula i want to include a logical test. In column D151:D i have multiple compagny names and i want to calculate only the VAT for one Compagny.

I tryed:

```
=IF(D151:D = "COMPAGNY.";SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(J151:J/100% *I151:I));"")

=SUMIF(D151:D;"COMPAGNY";ARRAYFORMULA(J151:J/100% *I151:I))
```

And i tryed with a filter as well. But i get ERROR's #NA's #VALUE's

Can somebody help me with this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D1:D151="COMPAGNY"; J1:J151/100% * I1:I151; )))
```

Comment: YES!, thats it. Really simple now i have seen it!